# Oracle Execute to parse ratio

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

In DB AWR report  I can see there is ~1:1 ratio of count of executions and count of parsing for all SQLs.
Can you please help me here. All my SQLs are using bind variables.
We are using: OJDBC7 , myBatis and Oracle database

Regards,
Vijay Maske

Comment: Your *parse* should be only a *soft parse* (and you re-use the cached cursors), so you should not observe serious problems. The only *advice* you can receive to get rid of *parsing* is not to use `ORM`. `ORM` typically lack the ability to *prepareStatement* outside a loop and *reuse it* inside.

Comment: Thank you @MarmiteBomber . Yes its indeed soft parse. We review AWR again and found 99.99% soft parses.

Comment: Soft parses are still expensive compared to no parse. Do you have the implicit statement cache enabled? If not that's likely your problem. Otherwise, I can't tell you why you are seeing so many soft parses. The Oracle Database JDBC driver does all it can to avoid them, but what it can do is constrained by the code you write. Also we always recommend using the latest version of the driver, currently 21. So if you are using Java 8 or later you should switch to the 21 version of the driver on Maven Central.

Comment: HI @DouglasSurber, thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that we are using Hikari Datasource. I just checked that CachePrepStmts property is already true.